# Making string series in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem in Python I simply can't wrap my head around, even though it's fairly simple (I think).

I'm trying to make "string series". I don't really know what it's called, but it goes like this:

I want a function that makes strings that run in series, so that every time the functions get called it "counts" up once.

I have a list with "a-z0-9._-" (a to z, 0 to 9, dot, underscore, dash). And the first string I should receive from my method is ***aaaa***, next time I call it, it should return ***aaab***, next time ***aaac*** etc. until I reach ***----***

Also the length of the string is fixed for the script, but should be fairly easy to change.

(Before you look at my code, I would like to apologize if my code doesn't adhere to conventions; I started coding Python some days ago so I'm still a noob).

What I've got:

*Generating my list of available characters*

```
chars = []
for i in range(26):
    chars.append(str(chr(i + 97)))

for i in range(10):
    chars.append(str(i))

chars.append('.')
chars.append('_')
chars.append('-')
```

*Getting the next string in the sequence*

```
iterationCount = 0
nameLen = 3
charCounter = 1
def getString():
    global charCounter, iterationCount
    name = ''
    for i in range(nameLen):
        name += chars[((charCounter + (iterationCount % (nameLen - i) )) % len(chars))]
    charCounter += 1
    iterationCount += 1
    return name
```

And it's the `getString()` function that needs to be fixed, specifically the way *name* gets build.

I have this feeling that it's possible by using the right "modulu hack" in the index, but I can't make it work as intended!

Comment: Look up how to create and use a Python Generator for this.

Comment: That's definately fix my iteration problem. But the problem is how to actually generate the strings :)

Comment: @mata beat me too it.  I was going to say you will be amazed at how easy the solution will be.

Comment: doens't make you less cool, thanks for trying at least :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you try to do can be done very easily using generators and `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

def getString(length=4, characters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789._-'):
    for s in itertools.product(characters, repeat=length):
        yield ''.join(s)

for s in getString():
    print(s)


aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
aaae
aaaf
...
```

Comment: Since it is a generator, it will automatically stop when it gets to the end of the itertools.product sequence.

Comment: Would be better to call `len` - `length` so as to not shadow the builtin, and `itertools.product(*([characters]*len))` seems a bit convoluted - I would suggest `itertools.product(characters, repeat=length)`

Comment: @JonClements - you're right :) `pydoc itertools.product` doesn't mention the `repeat` keyword argument (at least not right on top)

Comment: As they write in the tutorial; "Batteries included". This was the exact answer I was looking for :) Thanks mata! That was awesome.. Once again SO is a dazzeling magical place for knowledge.